# How do I create a shelveset of my excluded changes in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

What is the easiest way to shelve my excluded changes in visual studio 2013?    I'm looking at least for an option two swap my included and excluded changes but I can't find that either.

Answer (score -2):

Are you working with TFS?

If yes, use this vs extension:
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ae71e276-e35e-47d3-915d-61a5a38de33b

Comment: Yes, I'm using tfs.  However, I don't see how this plugin helps create a shelve for just my excluded changes.  It appears to be for auto-shelving.

Comment: Which in my understating help you achieve the required behavior.

Comment: I want a shelveset of only the items under 'excluded' changes.  Not a shelveset created automatically every 'x' minutes.

Comment: If I understood you, the following link may help - http://merrickchaffer.blogspot.co.il/2014/05/unshelving-just-items-you-want-in-vs2013.html?m=1

Comment: Downvoted, this plugin has nothing to do with swapping Included / Excluded changes or shelving the Excluded ones seperately.